# Getting a string's length in words not in characters? (Swift)

Tags: ios, string, swift, text

I am trying to retrieve the word count for the text in a `UITextView`. I can do this already with characters, as in counting the number of letters/spaces, but want the counter to show the number of words instead.

Can't seem to find anything in the documentation, unless it is in there and I don't understand what it is saying.

Comment: Can you edit your question to understand what you mean exactly?

Comment: Very unclear what you're asking

Comment: Sorry I've changed it a bit

Comment: Ok now I understand what you want. 1 sec

Answer (score 3):

To get the word count in a string you can split the string with separator " "(space)

```
let str = "asd asd asd"

print(str.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").count) // Prints: 3
```

Comment: This won't work in some cases. What if the user types "one,two,three"?

Comment: .... too bad x) I tihnk there is a function to separate with a set of characters.

Comment: Yes exist, but I'm afraid that this is not enough, this case need an extra work, removing special characters, then matching, etc

Answer (score 0):

If you only allow letters:

```
let str = "one,two"
str.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet().invertedSet).count
```

However in full disclosure this would count words with apostrophes as two words.